# SwiftUI updates Binding value with outdated value

Tags: swiftui, data-binding

I am using UDF-like architecture and my view receiving it's view state as enum case with payload wrapped.
In example code I expect that user can open **Alert** with **Textfield**, type name and after closing **Alert** typed text should be saved in attached **ViewStore**.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isAlertShowing: Bool = false
    @StateObject var viewStore = ViewStore()

    var body: some View {

        switch viewStore.state {
        case .preparing:
            EmptyView()

        case .initialized(let stateStyleName):
            let styleName = Binding<String>(        //A
                get: { return stateStyleName },
                set: { viewStore.setStyleName($0) }
            )

            ZStack {
                VStack(spacing: 15) {
                    Text("viewStore: \(stateStyleName)")
                        .padding(.bottom, 300)

                    Button("Button") {
                        isAlertShowing.toggle()
                    }
                }
            }
            .alert("My alert", isPresented: $isAlertShowing) {
                alertSaveContent(styleName: styleName)
            }
        }
    }

    @ViewBuilder
    private func alertSaveContent(styleName: Binding<String>) -> some View {
        TextField("Type name...", text: styleName)
    }
}

class ViewStore: ObservableObject {
    @Published var state: State

    init() {
        self.state = .initialized("My widget")
    }

    func setStyleName(_ name: String) {
        state = .initialized(name)
    }

    enum State {
        case preparing
        case initialized(String)
    }
}
```

The problem is after I have finished typing and the alert is closed, the **Binding** with comment *//A* receiving initial value "**My widget**".
I tried to take away enum wrapper **State** and all work as expected, but this wrapper is part of architecture and could not be removed.

The question is not how to fix this, the question is why is this happen? Could you please explain in detail what is happening with *//A* **Binding** after **Alert** is closing, and how enum wrapper is influencing this behaviour?

Comment: Why not use `@State var styleName: ...` and pass _it_ as a @Binding to alert as `$styleName`? You still can set it the same way you do (although this is a bad practice to change the data while constructing the view, but that's a different issue)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I'm trying to understand what is wrong with original approach

Comment: A few things: usage of locally defined `Binding<String>` is a kludge, the workaround we have to use sometimes when no better option is possible (but it's possible in your case). Having state altered during the view rendition is a bad practice (furthermore, you already have an ObservableObject, so why not make those decisions there, while let view should only care about: "do I display this element or not") And even `alertSaveContent(styleName: Binding<String>)` has no advantage since you are defining it in the same class, so why complicate things and not just link it to some state variable?

Comment: ^^^ Everything Tim said. But if you really want to know what's programmatically wrong with your current approach, add a print statement in your set for the local binding such that: ```print("set: \($0) \(stateStyleName)")```. You'll observe that when you type in the alert TextField, the print statement outputs as expected. But when you hit the "done" button, the Binding is triggering 1 more time and calling ```setStyleName``` with the value of ```stateStyleName``` before the alert is shown.

Comment: timbre, thank you for your detailed answer.
I am aware of using local binding, and I using it in rare cases when I have no other choice, for example, where SwiftUI expects Bindings. I am agree that approach in my example is not one of those cases.
I am wonder how to initialize local @State variable, do you think placing  "on Appear()" on view in .initialized() case will do the job properly?

Comment: @ZachtheBoB, thank you for explonation, I almost got it. The only thing left that make me wonder is why "the Binding is triggering 1 more time" after alert closing?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure why the binding is triggering more than once. To initialize a @State variable: In an ```init``` for your view do: ```self._isAlertShowing = State(initialValue: false)```